# Qt crashes on close after creating c++ registered QAbstractListModels

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm developing a test UI in QML and C++, and am having a problem where everything seemingly works fine during use, but then I get a debug error upon trying to close the window.

The debug error is as follows: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it an unusual way."

I've pinpointed the problem to QAbstractListModel-derived classes that I've made, as the program doesn't give me this error when I remove them from the QML code (they both cause the debug error). Does anyone have any idea as to what could be causing this?

I'm using cmake to build the program, so could I be missing a DLL that for some reason only causes a crash on exit?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: And when you run the program in a debugger, where does the crash happen? (Remember to look at the function call stack!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your model has a bug, ot it just does not follow the contract. Check out [Qt Model Test](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Model_Test) to verify your model.

If that does not let you spot the problem, try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Possibly create a smaller test program, or valgrind the Qt Model Test app from above.

If model passes all this, then it's not the model... ;)

---

Other common(?) bugs are double delete (first by parent, then by you), or delete of instance while its method is executing (usually a slot). If you do explicit deletes of QObjects, check those, and try changing those to use [deleteLater() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater).

Oh, and do not use smart pointers with objects which have parent (or other owning object), unless owner explicitly supports that smart pointer type (for QObjects, QPointer or QWeakPointer). Otherwise, risk of double delete.

Comment: I did a bit more messing around this morning, and seem to have pinpointed the problem to something that involves cmake. Using the exact same models in a Qt Creator project works fine, so while I'm not sure what exactly the problem is, I believe cmake is the issue. If I figure out the issue I'll post the solution. Regardless, thanks for the guidance!